# R: how to count the number of times two elements have the same ID (perhaps using the outer function)

Tags: r

I have the following three dimensional array:

```
dput(a)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 
7, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 
6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 
7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 
7, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 
7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 
3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 
3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 13, 
2, 3, 13, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 15, 17, 2, 15, 17, 2, 15, 17, 
2, 3, 5, 2, 15, 17, 2, 3, 13, 2, 15, 17, 2, 15, 17, 2, 3, 13, 
2, 3, 5, 2, 15, 17, 2, 15, 17, 2, 3, 5, 2), .Dim = c(3L, 20L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("cl.tmp", "cl.tmp", "cl.tmp"), NULL, 
    NULL))
```

The dimension of this array (a) is 3x20x6 (after edits).

I wanted to count the proportion of times that a[,i,] matches a[,j,] element-by-element in the matrix. Basically, I wanted to get mean(a[,i,] == a[,j,]) for all i, j, and I would like to do this fast but in R.

It occurred to me that the outer function might be a possibility but I am not sure how to specify the function. Any suggestions, or any other alternative ways?

The output would be a 20x20 symmetric matrix of nonnegative elements with 1 on the diagonals.

The solution given below works (thanks!) but I have one further question (sorry).

I would like to display the coordinates above in a heatmap. I try the following:

```
n<-dim(a)[2]
xx <- matrix(apply(a[,rep(1:n,n),]==a[,rep(1:n,each=n),],2,sum),nrow=n)/prod(dim(a)[-2])
image(1:20, 1:20, xx, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

This gives me the following heatmap.

[image]

However, I would like to display (reorder the coordinate) such that I get all the coordinates that have high-values amongst each other together. However, I would not like to bias the results by deciding on the number of groups myself. I tried

```
hc <- hclust(as.dist(1-xx), method = "single")
```

but I can not decide how to cut the resulting tree to decide on bunching the coordinates together. Any suggestions? Bascically, in the figure, I would like the coordinate pairs in the top left (and bottom right off-diagonal blocks) to be as low-valued (in this case as red) as possible.

Looking around on SO, I found that there exists a function heatmap which might do this,

```
heatmap(xx,Colv=T,Rowv=T, scale='none',symm = T)
```

and I get the following:

[image]

which is all right, but I can not figure out how to get rid of the dendrograms on the sides or the axes labels. It does work if I extract out and do the following:

```
yy <- heatmap(xx,Colv=T,Rowv=T, scale='none',symm = T,keep.dendro=F)
image(1:20, 1:20, xx[yy$rowInd,yy$colInd], xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

so I guess that is what I will stick with. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 400x400 matrix will be the output.

Comment: But good point, I was not thinking that it would be possible but I will reduce it to a 3x 20x6 array. Hopefully that will have enough common elements to be useful.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to count the number of times that matrices `a[,i,]` and `a[,j,]` are identical for each i,j? Or you want to have the number of common elements for each i,j?

Comment: I would like to have the propotion of commons elements between a[,i,]  and a[,j,]. So, for each (i,j), I would get a number in [0, 1].

Comment: can you explain how will be 400 x 400 output matrix?

Comment: sorry the example has been changed to be a 3x20x6 array so the net result will be a 20x20 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
n<-dim(a)[2]
matrix(apply(a[,rep(1:n,n),]==a[,rep(1:n,each=n),],2,sum),nrow=n)/prod(dim(a)[-2])
```

It has to be stressed that the memory usage of this method goes with `n^2` so you might have trouble to use it with larger arrays.